# Google Drive API giving Insufficient Permission for uploading a file

Tags: java, google-api, google-drive-api, google-oauth, google-api-java-client

I'm trying to upload a image to google drive but it is returning '**Insufficient Permission: Request had insufficient authentication scopes**.' I tried changing the scopes to `DriveScopes.DRIVE_FILE`, `DriveScopes.DRIVE` but it still throws the same error.

I'm using the sample code provided in google developer documentation

Java Quick start guide: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/java

Upload File: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads

I enabled the drive api with desktop app option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you re-authenticate the user when you changed the scope. It needs to pop up and request consent again.

If you dont know what i am talking about.  Go remove the file stored here

```
.setDataStoreFactory(new FileDataStoreFactory(new java.io.File(TOKENS_DIRECTORY_PATH)))
```

Comment: Is there any way to reauthenticate without deleting the file?

Comment: you could delete the consent in your google account.   Sending a call to the revoke endpoing should work as well.

Comment: OMG you've saved my day. I had kept getting 403 with scope "drive.file" when uploading a file till I read this post.

Comment: FYI anyone using Google Drive API v3 sample and getting 403, System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir")); go there and delete the "StoredCredential" file.

Comment: This answer is underrated. This little detail about re-authenticating is missing from so many docs and tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

When I ran created a GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow in a unit test the "StoredCredential" file was created in a "tokens" directory located in the root of my Intellij project.